# execute server call first then next line of code

Tags: java, android, android-volley

i want to execute Toast with text "tex2" first then Toast with text "text1" but 
 in  my code it print  in reverse order when i execute the code(i mean different code with same structure) bellow.
(say i want to wait for reponse then execute next)

```
class A
{
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) 
    {
       getdatafromnet();
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "text1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       //..................code
    }

    void getdatafromnet()
    {
       //volley server call
       stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url2,
                new Response.Listener<String>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "text2",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                 });

       //....follwing volley parameters and calls
     }
}
```

Comment: Your are aware that toeas toes not provide any response to your code? It is just to show user that something is happened.  Fire and forget

Comment: there is another code instead of Toast ,i used Toast as an example  to clear execution flow  i wanted to have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want some operation to be performed after server call returns. Better put your code inside onResponse method or call a function from within onResponse method.

Comment: Is there no other way to wait for response then execute next line other than your way.

Comment: Till now I used the way I explained to you. Even in official documentation for MediaPlayer Library, for requesting permissions in android, for requesting external URIs, I find only this type of approach.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no other approach to wait till the response in android. e.g. for MediaPlayer you use prepareAsync and onPrepared listner.

Comment: If you want to make it little more complicated, you can make your own broadcast listener and do a broadcast when the function is done executing. The second function should then execute when your app receives broadcast.

Comment: hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Because the calling network is asynchronous, you could not get right result.
To process it, You can use android.os.Handler.

For example;

```
class A
{
 Handler m_handler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message inputMessage) {
       switch (inputMessage.what) {
            case 1:
                getdatafromnet();
                break;
            case 2:             
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "text1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //..................code
                break;
            default:
                super.handleMessage(inputMessage);
        }
    }
 };

 public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) 
  {
    m_handler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
  }

  void getdatafromnet()
  {
  //volley server call
    stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url2,
                new Response.Listener<String>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response)
                    {
                      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "text2",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                      m_handler.sendEmptyMessage(2);    
                    }//..........follwing volley parameters and calls
                 });
}
```